# Can anyone identify this power connector?

Tags: connector, identification

I'm looking to find the name of this type of connector:

[image]

The picture above is from a power adapter I have and provides 10v (not that that matters). If you can't tell from the image, it's basically a rectangle connector with a semi-circle notch taken out of the top-middle so you can't get the polarity wrong.

The rectangle is 13mm x 7mm.

Comment: Can you measure the pitch spacing, the distance between the center of the holes ?

Comment: The pitch spacing is 7mm. Also, the distance from the inside edge of one hole to the next is 5mm.

Comment: Best I could find is [this](http://www.tme.eu/en/details/tamiya-w/dc-power-connectors/) connector with a 6.2mm pitch. Try get a more precise measurement and see if it is actually 6.2mm pitch instead of 7mm. You might have to break the safety pin though.

Comment: I don't have digital calipers but when remeasuring it turns out you're spot on, looks like it's between 6mm and 6.5mm.

Comment: I've been talking to someone on eBay and for their Tamiya connector, the pitch spacing is 5.9mm. So it might be a bit of a push to fit but I'll keep looking! Thanks again.